# Get Wordpress theme, php file-URL via javascript

Tags: wordpress, url

I am using jQuery `load()` to load a PHP page at runtime. And I am not using an elegant way to get the PHP URL. Somebody tell me an elegant way?

**My method:**

```
'http://' + document.domain + '/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax/myload.php'
```

If my wp is under a sub dir,I have to change the url to this:

```
'http://' + document.domain + '/mysubdir/wp-content/themes/mytheme/ajax/myload.php'
```

this is so ugly!

Structure of code is;

- **index.php** contains **a.js**
- **a.js** uses ajax to load **tpl.php** (just echo some div) into **index.php**
- **tpl.php** is in my theme path.

So the question is how to get the URL of **tpl.php** in **a.js**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `get_template_directory_uri`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

Also, `get_site_url` may come in handy as well.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url

And `get_bloginfo` gives you a bunch of stuff, like the site url and home directory url.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

---

Also, It sounds like you need to add a parameter to your JS code, which is "passed" from PHP.

For example (in pseudocode)

**a.js:**

```
loadDivFromThemePage(var themePagePath)
{
     // call ajax load with themePagePath variable
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<script>
loadDivFromThemePage(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/tpl.php" ?>)
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan,this is a pure external javascript code,I can't call php function from that file.Any Idea?

Comment: @Sam4Ever It might help if you provided a little more information on your exact situation. Do you have access to the wordpress code/server, or is this for a third party site? If you have access to the wordpress code/server, and the problem is that you can't use php in a certain file, you can create a php file on the server which will return the values of the above functions for you to use. You would then call this php file via ajax, get the proper url as a response string, and use it in the client side javascript.

Comment: The structure is --> <br/>1,index.php contains a.js.<br/>2,a.js ajax load tpl.php(just echo some div) into index.php.<br/>3,tpl.php is in my theme path.<br/>So the question is how to get the url of tpl.php in a.js? Thank you Bryan.

Comment: @Sam4Ever I have edited your question with that info and added to my answer a possible solution. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan,LOL,forgot that I can use parameter!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use wp_localize_script.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

For example, in my javascript I call the variable 'myLocalized' when I need my path. I use Angular with WordPress. My code is below:

```js
function() mes_scripts{
   wp_register_script(
     'angularjs',
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'
   );
 
   wp_register_script(
     'angularjs-route',
     get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js'
   );
 
 wp_enqueue_script(
   'my-scripts',
   get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js',
   array('angularjs', 'angularjs-route' )
 );

  wp_localize_script(
    'my-scripts',
    'myLocalized',
    array(
      'partials' => trailingslashit( get_template_dir
      )
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mes_scripts' );
```